# Make Text Layer Completely Transparent

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency

How do I make the word Virgo transparent so it shows the background of this image (background is obviously transparent)? I am using Photoshop.

I tried grouping layer 2 and the text layer and changing the blending mode options but it didn't work.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Hold down <kbd>control</kbd> and click the thumbnail of the layer with the text on it in the layers palette. (Or "select" > "load selection" > "ok") The "marching ants" will appear around your text, indicating you have made a selection.
2. Hit <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> to invert your selection. (Or "select" > "inverse")
3. Highlight the layer with the artwork.
4. Hit the layer "Add layer mask" button at the bottom of the layers palette.
5. Turn off, or delete, the layer with the text, since at the moment it is the layer which is "filling" your newly created hole :)

Alternatively, you can avoid making a layer mask by simply making your selection, highlighting your art layer and hitting the <kbd>delete</kbd> key, but that's seen as a "destructive" way to work, and is not the recommended approach. (Again you'll have to hide, or delete your original text layer to "reveal" the hole)

Comment: Thank you so much! I searched for hours for this answer!